# NullReferenceException when installing Sitecore SXA

Tags: sxa, installation, packages

I have a fresh installation of Sitecore 9.0.1 rev 171219 and am attempting to install SXA 1.6.  I've downloaded the package and when attempting to install it, it fails with the following error in the logs:

> ManagedPoolThread #7 09:11:03 INFO Installing item:
>   items/master/sitecore/system/Modules/Layout Service/Rendering Contents
>   Resolvers/SXA/Page List Contents
>   Resolver/{93FC6E4C-9119-4C05-B8B5-41446A9BB5FA}/en/1/xml
>
> ManagedPoolThread #7 09:11:03 INFO Installing item:
>   items/master/sitecore/system/Modules/Layout Service/Rendering Contents
>   Resolvers/SXA/Rich Text Contents
>   Resolver/{192EFE3F-F0C8-49D0-AEED-6F233F36CCC3}/en/1/xml
>
> ManagedPoolThread #7 09:11:03 ERROR One or more exceptions occurred
>   while processing the subscribers to the 'item:saved' event.
>
> Exception[1]: System.NullReferenceException
>
> Message[1]: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Source[1]: Sitecore.Marketing.xMgmt
>
> at Sitecore.Marketing.xMgmt.Definitions.ItemEventHandler.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.b__0(Guid
>   templateId)
>
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1
>   source, Func`2 predicate) at
>   Sitecore.Marketing.xMgmt.Definitions.ItemEventHandler.DeployItem(Item
>   item)
>
> at Sitecore.Events.Event.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String
>   eventName, Object[] parameters, EventResult result)
>
> ManagedPoolThread #7 09:11:03 ERROR Failed to save the item. Item ID: {FA86AD54-9CEC-4509-9EFD-DD6DBC608A5B}, database: master

I've searched all over and cannot find a way around this issue.

Has anyone encountered this before?

Any ideas on how I can get past this?

Comment: is it Solr up and running?

Comment: Yes Solr is running properly.  There were errors previously that required a dynamicfield entry; however, Solr is running without issue now.

Comment: @JamesEggers - Have you installed SPE (Powershell extensions) 4.7.2 before installing SXA?

Comment: @PeterProchazka The error disappeared after installing SPE.  Thanks!!

Comment: Glad I could help @JamesEggers. Definitely misleading error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error could be caused by missing SPE module. Try to install Sitecore PowerShell Extensions 4.7.2 which is a prerequisite for SXA 1.6