# Sitecore 9 Sxa Install throwing NullReferenceException Error

Tags: sxa, installation

I have `Sitecore 9 update 2` installed. I am trying to install `SXA (Sitecore Experience Accelerator 1.7.1 rev. 180604 for 9.0)`. I have already installed `SPE (Sitecore PowerShell Extensions-4.7.2 for Sitecore 8/9)`. When I install SXA I get this error.

```
ERROR One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 
   'packageinstall:items:ended' event.
   Exception[1]: System.NullReferenceException 
    Message[1]: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
    Source[1]: Sitecore.ContentSearch 
   at 

Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler.IsExcludedFromIndex(SitecoreIndexableItem indexable, Boolean checkLocation)
```

I have tried this [thread](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/11155/nullreferenceexception-when-installing-sitecore-sxa) and this [thread](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/509/installing-package-acting-different-between-2-environments) but neither help identify the issue.

The second thread seems most aligned but it is unclear what was found in the configs that fixed the issue. From what I have read my versions all align correctly. I am installing this on a base install with the website just running `HelixBase`.